# expectation of an exponential function

Tags: expected-value

What is the expectation of an exponential function: 
$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(A x)] = \exp((1/2) A^2)\,?$$

I am struggling to find references that shows this, can anyone help me please?

I am assuming Gaussian distribution.

A is a constant and x is a random variable that is gaussian distributed.

Comment: What are you actually asking here?  For help with a derivation?

Comment: It's considered bad form to cross-post things to multiple SE sites (math.SE and here, in this case). Please chose *one* which you think is appropriate and post it there. This question has already been answered on math.SE.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258761/expectation-of-an-exponential-function.  Although questions like this are (marginally) on topic here, this is a purely math question that has been asked and answered on that site, so I'm closing this copy of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia's page on the [log-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) has the more general result for distributions with non-zero location parameter $\mu$.

It notes that, for the lognormal distribution defined as:

$$X = e^{\mu + \sigma Z}$$

with $Z$ a standard normal variable, the expectation is:

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}$$